# Hashicorp - Multiple credential pairs in a single object

Tags: passwords, credentials, application-server, hashicorp-vault, consul-template

Let's say, I have two users `online` and `batch` who do CRUD operations on resources of a custom server. These two users have different access levels for different resources. I want to create *one* object such that, the server recognizes the credential pair*s* *and* only one particular pair is used by an application as required.

In particular, the server requires the credential pair in the format as shown below.

```sh
online:password1
batch:password2
```

Suppose, I build an object such as `kv/server/server-acl` with the following.

```sh
key1=online
val1=password1
key2=batch
val2=password2
```

How do I transform the above to `username:password` format for the server to consume?

Note that, the above object is helpful when providing credentials to applications. For example, I can use the `vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-server : "kv/server/server-acl"` annotation and for an online application, render with `{{ .Data.data.key1 }}` and `{{ .Data.data.val1 }}` for user name and password respectively.

Comment: It seems, creation of multiple key-value pairs is the norm as opposed to having multiple key-pairs in a single object (as mentioned in my example above). See here: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/multiple-key-value-pairs-in-secrets-path-and-certificate-authentication/8679